# Question about subfield subcode of a cyclic code

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

> If $C$ is a cyclic code over $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, then $C|_{\mathbb{F}_q}$ is a cyclic code over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

I know this holds for a linear code, what about a cyclic code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679500/15941 ?

Comment: just read it, but does that hold when C is cyclic?

Comment: If all the symbols in a particular codeword are in the subfield, does this property hold for cyclic shifts of that codeword?